# How to measure memory bandwidth of an app?

Tags: performance, perf

My coworkers are trying to figure out a performance problem. I suspect they're reading lots of unnecessary memory and hitting a memory bandwidth problem but I don't want to suggest that unless I know how to check it.

How do I measure? Is there an easy example I can test before suggesting it? I figure maybe using dd on dev zero and null may work of writing a zero file to tmp could work?

I tried looking at `perf list` for clues but I don't think I saw an option. I use an AMD but most of the machines are intel. I tagged perf but I don't necessarily need the solution to be perf